# Error when post a message on user wall using Facebook PHP SDK Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I have a Facebook Application and when i try send a post to wall of some users i get this Exception from Faceboo Last API for PHP.

Mensagem: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 2147483647

But when i send to some others users it works fine, all users that im testing already authorize my apps.

What can be the error?

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same issue, it was because, I used php function intval() on the FacebookId, which was stored as string.. I used trim instead, and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using `intval()` function or storing the IDs into a Integer database column, because some Facebook IDs are outside the 32 bit integers.
2147483647 is the greatest int32 value.

Answer (score 0):

That user id doesn't exist or has opted out of the Facebook platform (Home -> Privacy Settings -> Apps and Websites -> Turn Off All Platform Apps -> Turn Off Platform.  You can see that this ID doesn't exist by going to this url: https://graph.facebook.com/2147483647

Comment: Hi @OffBySome, when i get this error with message: "Some of the aliases you requested do not exist" is because he disable platform?

Comment: It could be that or you could just have a invalid id.

Comment: Hi, im using now a new FQL to only show users that have my app. But the same problem occur and i get this error when other user try send a wall post to me using my app, but the problem dont occur when i send to this same person. example: when i send to my wife or to me i have succes, but when my wife or other try send to me facebook show an exception. it can be because my app is new and dont be published (avaliable for public) yet?

Comment: Yeah make sure your app isnt in sandbox mode if you want others to test it.

Comment: Hi, my app is not on sandbox mode: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/189/capturadetela20111019s1.png/